# jQuery get td width

Tags: jquery, width, html-table

I want to learn with jQuery "td width", for an example:

```
if(td.width=="100"){
    alert("td width = 100");
}
```

Please explain.

```
<table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="100">Number</td>
        <td width="50">Order</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100">1</td>
        <td width="50">Car</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

here's a simple extension, the css could be edited to do something less intrusive.

```
var tdWidthLimit = 100;

$('td').each(function() {
    tdWidth = $(this).width();
    if (tdWidth >= tdWidthLimit)
    {    
        alert('hightlighted td width is ' + tdWidth);
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#f00'});
    }
});
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/py26n/)​

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td').each(function(){
      if($(this).width() == 100){
           alert(this.textContent + " width = 100");
      }
});
```

This will look through all your tds and then alert the td's text content and "width = 100" if the width is 100

Answer (score 0):

jQuery width is a method, you need to call the method:

```
if(td.width() === 100) {
    alert("td width = 100");
}
```

and td must be a jQuery object of course. Note that it will take the first element in the jQuery object collection and get its width. if you have many elements in that you need to use .each() to loop every element in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
if($('table td').width() == 100) {
    alert('width == ' + $('table td').width());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a little read at [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) if you wish to understand jQuery better.

In your current example it should look something like this:

```
if($('td').width() === 100) {
    alert("td width = 100");
}
```

Notice that it will have problems if case you have more than one `td` element in your page, so I suggest you think of a more specific query selector.